# XMPP CORS domain error

Tags: javascript, xmpp, openfire, strophe

I had created my own chat server with openfire. I tried to do http-bind using http i could able to bind with openfire server. My web application is running on https, so i tried to bind with https request, I'm getting "CROS origin error" with reason (CORS request failed). I had allowed-access-origin as *. In HTTP Binding cross-domain policy.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
 <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
 <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="5222,5223,7070,7443" secure="true"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Is any issues on my configuration. Please give me a solution to it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check, SSL ports are enabled. If everything is enabled check the SSL certificate is verified certificate. If its not a verified certificate, else add the certificate exception to your browser. It will work.

I had fixed the SSL error by adding this.

All the best